# giboon mailchimp 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

I am using the ROR Gem Gibonn by Amro for integration with mailchimp.
I have followed the how-to at https://github.com/amro/gibbon. When I attempt to add a new subscriber I receive a 404 error "ResourceNotFound". Thing is I am not sure what "Resource" is not found.

Here is my _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag('/emailapi/subscribe', method: "post", id: "subscribe") do -%>
   <%= text_field(:FNAME, :fname, { placeholder: "First Name"}) %>
   <%= text_field(:LNAME, :lname, { placeholder: "Last Name"}) %>
   <%= email_field(:email, :email_address, { placeholder: "Email Address"}) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Sign me up!") %>
```

<% end %>`

Here is my emailapi_controller.rb

```
class EmailapiController < ApplicationController
def index
end

def subscribe
    @list_id = "3ea2e9a0c8"
    gb = Gibbon::Request.new

    gb.lists(:list_id).members.create(body: {
                                        email_address: "email_address",
                                        status: "subscribed",
                                        merge_fields: {
                                                        FNAME: "fname",
                                                        LNAME: "lname"
                                                        }
                                        })


   flash[:success] = "Thank you for pay-it-forward.
   You are now added to our email list."
   redirect_to '/'
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

You have an erroneous `:` in front of `list_id` in `gb.lists(:list_id).members.create`.

If you change that to `gb.lists(list_id).members.create` it should work.

Comment: I gave it a try and received this error "undefined local variable or method `list_id' for #<EmailapiController:0x007f6880b4adf8>"

Comment: with further investigation I have made it work however i am not seeing the email address add to my mailchimp list.  I have gone back in and added the double_optin and set to false to make sure I am not missing a confirm email. at this point i am not sure.

Comment: did you ever figure this out.. I'm having a similiar issue